# Should we re-import data every time we add any changes in solrconfig.xml or schema.xml?

Tags: xml, solr, lucene

I have added few changes in `schema.xml` file to match the results for words like *"Sachintendulkar"*, this should show results for *"Sachin Tendulkar"* by simply changing `catenateAll="0"` to `1` in the following filter:

```
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
```

My question is, **everytime I make any change in schema.xml file, do I need to re-import data?**

I am using *Solr API*.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily for all changes in schema.xml, but for changes like the one you mention, that affect what data is indexed, then yes, you need to re-import the data.

You could make changes that affect how requests are processed, and then you wouldn't need to re-index the data.